# PostgreSQLEnumType does not get recognized as UserType by scala

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, scala, hibernate, annotations

Environment:

Hibernate 6.2.13.Final

Spring Boot 3.1.5

Scala 2.13.12

I'm trying to persist an enum which looks like this:

```
public enum ProductType {
   MAIN, SUPPLEMENT
}
```

In the entity it's annotated like this:

```
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.`type`.basic.PostgreSQLEnumType

@NotNull
@BeanProperty
@Type(classOf[PostgreSQLEnumType])
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
var productType: ProductType = _
```

Which works in our Kotlin apps(we are upgrading from spring boot 2 to 3 all over). But when doing the same in Scala the compiler complains about the types...

```
ProductAttributeEntity.scala:44:16: type mismatch;
 found   : Class[io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.basic.PostgreSQLEnumType](classOf[io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.basic.PostgreSQLEnumType])
 required: Class[_ <: org.hibernate.usertype.UserType[_]]
```

I'm using this version of the hypersistence lib

```
implementation("io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62:$hypersistenceVersion")
```

Without the
`@Type(classOf[PostgreSQLEnumType])` annotation I get a runtime error because the type is not en psql enum type but a varchar, when inserting into the db.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement [ERROR: column "product_type" is of type dbtest.product_type but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 184] [insert into dbtest.product_attribute (add_seat,changed,companion_guard,created,organisation_id,product_id,product_type,replace_main_seat,seating_properties) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into dbtest.product_attribute (add_seat,changed,companion_guard,created,organisation_id,product_id,product_type,replace_main_seat,seating_properties) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256)
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can solve this with Scala?